# y(t) a of an integrator circuit

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, lowpass-filter, fourier, integration

I have a signal $$ x(t)= \frac{1}{T} e^{-\frac{t}{T}} u(t) - \frac{1}{T} e^{\frac{t}{T}} u(-t) $$

and I know that it transits in a integrator circuit and I have to find y(t) in time and frequency domain. From theory on my book i know that

$$ y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} x(\tau) d \tau $$

So I started to calculate this integral with my $x(t)$:

$$ \frac{1}{-RCT} \left[ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{\frac{-\tau}{T}} d\tau - \int_{—\infty}^{0} e^{\frac{\tau}{T}}d\tau \right] $$

but this gave me

$$ \frac{1}{-RCT} \left[  \dfrac{e^{-\infty } -1}{-\frac{1}{T}} - \dfrac{-e^{-\infty } +1}{\frac{1}{T}} \right] $$

and this gave me 0.

The correct result should be $$ -e^{ -\frac{|t|}{T} } $$

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The input and the integrator output are shown below:

[image]

So, you should consider two cases: $t<0$ and $t>0$.

In the first case ($t<0$), you have 
$$\begin{align}
y(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^t x(\tau)d\tau = -\frac{1}{T}\int_{-\infty}^t e^{\frac{\tau}{T}}u(-\tau)d\tau \\
&= -\frac{1}{T}\int_{-\infty}^t e^{\frac{\tau}{T}}d\tau = -\frac{1}{T}Te^{\frac{\tau}{T}}\Big]_{-\infty}^t \\
&= -e^{\frac{\tau}{T}}\Big]_{-\infty}^{t} = -(e^{\frac{t}{T}} - 0) = -e^{\frac{t}{T}}
\end{align}$$
again, for $t<0$. So now you have
$$y(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-e^{\frac{t}{T}}, & t < 0 \\
? \quad \:\:\:, & t > 0
\end{array}\right.$$
and you're looking for the other branch of the output. Can you show that it is $$y(t) = -e^{-\frac{t}{T}}, \quad t > 0?$$

If you do, then you'll get
$$y(t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
-e^{\frac{t}{T}}, & t < 0 \\
-e^{-\frac{t}{T}},  & t > 0
\end{array}\right.= -e^{-\frac{|t|}{T}}$$ for all $t$.

Comment: I though I understood and for t>0 I wrote $$  y(t) = \int_{t}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{T} e^{\frac{\tau}{T}} u(\tau) d\tau $$ but this gave me $$ \frac{1}{T} [ \frac{0 - e^{\frac{-t}{T} }}{-\frac{1}{T}} ]$$ that is $$ e^{-\frac{t}{T} } $$

And I have also another question.. what about $$ \frac{-1}{RC} $$ ?? thank you !! You’re better than Wikipedia 

Comment: No, that's not the correct integral. Check the figure. You have to integrate from $-\infty$ up to $t$. According to the figure you should split the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$, which includes the left part of the signal $x(\tau)$, and from $X$ to $Y$ to include the right part of the signal, up to $t$. What are $X$ and $Y$? :)

Comment: Checking the figure ( thank for that !) I should have integrate the left part of the graph from $$ -\infty $$ to $$ 0 $$ and the right part from $$ 0 $$ to $$ t $$. The sum of these two integrals give me the result of y(t) for t>0. Now the result is correct!! thanks!!!

Comment: The question about the constant 1/RC is about the fact that I study on my book that if x(t) enters on a integrator circuit , so $$ y(t) = \frac{1}{RC} \int_{- \infty}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau $$ but when we studied the signal for t<0 e t>0 we ignore the this constant. This formula $$ y(t) = \frac{1}{RC} \int_{- \infty}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau $$  is what I study in my book

Comment: How can I demonstrate it for the frequency domain ? I found that $$ X(f) = \frac{1}{(1+ iwT)(1 - iwT)} $$ but it’s difficult to made the graph of this , cause of the real and immaginary part

Comment: $1/RC$ is just a constant, it propagates to the output. It does not affect the solution at all, you just get $-\frac{1}{RC} e^{-\frac{|t|}{T}}$ at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104138/discussion-between-gkh-and-elena-martini).

Comment: In the second left figure, integrate upto here should be upto $-t$?

Comment: @jomegaA, no, why should it? The range of integration is always from $-\infty$ to $t$, no matter what $t$ is, positive or negative. It's still $t$.